# issues with html 5 pushstate in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, pushstate

I am pretty new to Angular and currently building the authentication + navigation part of the app. I followed the ideas described in [this](https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth) useful github entry.

When users navigate to the app they are redirected to `<app>/login` which displays the login screen properly.

My problem is that in my implementation, unlike the tutorial, when the user sets the URL to `<app>/login` I am getting 404 instead of the proper page (
`<app>/#/login` works well).

I am using AngularJS v1.2.5, 
This is my application config file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
        function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

            var access = routingConfig.accessLevels;

            $routeProvider.when('/',
                {
                    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                    access: access.anon
                });

            $routeProvider.when('/login',
                {
                    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                    access: access.anon
                });

            $routeProvider.when('/404',
                {
                    templateUrl: 'views/404.html',
                    access: access.anon
                });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $location) {
                return {
                    'responseError': function (response) {
                        if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                            $location.path('/login');
                            return $q.reject(response);
                        }
                        else {
                            return $q.reject(response);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }])


    .run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$http', 'Auth', function ($rootScope, $location, $http, Auth) {

        $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
            $rootScope.error = null;
            if (!Auth.authorize(next.access)) {
                if(Auth.isLoggedIn()) $location.path('/');
                else                  $location.path('/login');
            }
            else {
                angular.element('body').removeClass('naked');
            }
        });

    }]);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you'll need to accomplish this. First you need to set your web server to support URL rewrite.

**For Apache HTTP Server** add an `.htaccess` to the root of your website and include this snippet. It will redirect all URLs to `index.html` if the file does not already exist.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Second, which you already have, is to add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` in the config of your AngularJS module. [Angular Doc: $location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location#!)

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
        function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  [...]

}]);
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to support URL rewrite for Jetty?  Would it just be a filter?